# create a sequence variable in R in a loop and if statement

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sequence

I have a data set with "week_number" and "year" as columns. For each  year I have week_number from 1 to 52 and I want to create a sequence variable such that for 10 years and 52 weeks in each year, it will go from 1 to 520. But I have other variables in the data file, so the length of the data file is not 520. I tried for loops (over week_number and year) and seq_along, but didn't work. Any suggestions? The data has 520X50 (states) and X 5 (categories) rows.

```
Week_num year state category volume 
1       2017 AK     x       123
2       2017 AK     x       125
3       2017 AK     x       125
4       2017 AK     x       123
5       2017 AK     x       125
6       2017 AK     x       125

for (z in seq_along(1:520)){
  for (j in data$week_num){
    for (i in data$year){
   if (data$week_num==j &data$year==i) {data$trend[nrow(i)]<-z}
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi ozlem. Can you create a minimal working example and show expected output based on that?

Comment: Hello @ozlem, please share a sample of your data. You can type in your console `dput(head(dataset))`and copy the output and paste into your question. I assume your data is named `dataset`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `row_number`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number(week_number, year))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `merge` is appropriate.

Sample data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:3, year = c(2010L, 2011L, 2012L), week = c(3L, 17L, 51L))
```

"Full" dataset of year/weeknumber:

```r
yearweeks <- expand.grid(week = 1:52, year = 2010:2012)
head(yearweeks)
#   week year
# 1    1 2010
# 2    2 2010
# 3    3 2010
# 4    4 2010
# 5    5 2010
# 6    6 2010
tail(yearweeks)
#     week year
# 151   47 2012
# 152   48 2012
# 153   49 2012
# 154   50 2012
# 155   51 2012
# 156   52 2012
```

The merge, where `NA` indicates a week that was not originally present. In this case, `id` and any other column in `dat` will be preserved (where present) and `NA` (where the year/week was missing).

```r
dat2 <- merge(dat, yearweeks, by = c("year", "week"), all = TRUE)
head(dat2)
#   year week id
# 1 2010    1 NA
# 2 2010    2 NA
# 3 2010    3  1
# 4 2010    4 NA
# 5 2010    5 NA
# 6 2010    6 NA
tail(dat2)
#     year week id
# 151 2012   47 NA
# 152 2012   48 NA
# 153 2012   49 NA
# 154 2012   50 NA
# 155 2012   51  3
# 156 2012   52 NA
```

From here, you can do whatever you need to convert year/week into your 1-520 sequence-variable.